# Using Kernel.apply to call private methods

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to dynamically call private methods in a module.

Kernel.apply is able to call public methods, but I get an undefined error when trying to call private methods, even from within the context of my module. Is there a way to have a method private but still dynamically called?

### Example

```
defmodule Test do
  def hello() do
    IO.puts("hello")
    Kernel.apply(Test, :world, []) # This works
    Kernel.apply(Test, :worldp, []) # But this doesn't
  end

  def world() do
    IO.puts("world")
  end

  defp worldp() do
    IO.puts("worldp")
  end
end
```

### Results

```
iex(2)> Test.hello
hello
world
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Test.worldp/0 is undefined or private. Did you mean one of:

      * world/0
```

Comment: What you want can't be done.

Comment: If you really need to call the function outside of the module make the function public.  Even if you could find a way to call a private function outside of the module, it'd be hacky. As @mudasobwa says below--private functions are intended to be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

`Kernel.apply(Test, :worldp, [])` just like `Test.worldp()`.

You can't call a private function outside a module.

You can try this:

```
defmodule Test do
  def hello() do
    IO.puts("hello")
    Kernel.apply(&worldp/0, [])
  end

  defp worldp() do
    IO.puts("worldp")
  end

end
Test.hello()
```

Comment: It's not dynamic, unfortunately.

Comment: @AnilRedshift it’s fortunately. You are not allowed to call private functions from outside the module and this is done on purpose. You also can nor comment private functions neither test them. Private functions are considered to be an implementation detail and if you find yourself in a need to call a private function from outside, you are doing it wrong. Period.